# Not able to figure out the way to call a function at the correct place in django website

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am working on a django website and have come across an error which I am not able to solve and Its been a couple of days but I wasnt able to solve the error. I am trying to integrate a payment gateway to my site. I have a payment button which on click is supposed to post the data to the database as well as go to the payment site. But it is storing the data but not going to payment site.
Here is the javascript for my button:

```
    document.getElementById('payment-info').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      submitFormData()
    })

    function submitFormData() {
      console.log('Payment Button Clicked')
      var userFormData = {
        'name': null,
      }

      var shippingInfo = {
        'address': null,
      }

      shippingInfo.address = form.address.value
      userFormData.name=form.name.value

      var url = "/process_order/"
      fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({'form': userFormData, 'shipping': shippingInfo }),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log('Success:', data);
          alert('Transaction Completed')
          window.location.href = "{% url 'index' %}"
        })

    }
  </script>
```

This is my views.py:

```
def processOrder(request):
    transaction_id = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer=request.user.customer
        order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        total=float(data['form']['total'])
        order.transaction_id=transaction_id

        if total == order.get_cart_total:
            order.complete = True
        order.save()    
        ShippingAddress.objects.create(
            customer=customer,
            order=order,
            address=data['shipping']['address'],
            name=data['form']['name'],
        )
    //Code for integration below

        param_dict = {

                'MID': 'DIY12386817555501617',
                'ORDER_ID': str(order.id),
                'TXN_AMOUNT': '4',
                'CUST_ID': 'j',
                'INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID': 'Retail',
                'WEBSITE': 'WEBSTAGING',
                'CHANNEL_ID': 'WEB',
                'CALLBACK_URL':'http://127.0.0.1:8000/handlerequest/',    
        }
   
        param_dict['CHECKSUMHASH'] = Checksum.generate_checksum(param_dict, MERCHANT_KEY)
        return render(request, 'paytm.html', {'param_dict': param_dict})

    return JsonResponse('Done',safe=False)
@csrf_exempt
def handlerequest(request):
    # paytm will send you post request here
    form = request.POST
    response_dict = {}
    for i in form.keys():
        response_dict[i] = form[i]
        if i == 'CHECKSUMHASH':
            checksum = form[i]

    verify = Checksum.verify_checksum(response_dict, MERCHANT_KEY, checksum)
    if verify:
        if response_dict['RESPCODE'] == '01':
            print('order successful')
        else:
            print('order was not successful because' + response_dict['RESPMSG'])
    
    return HttpResponse('doneee')
```

And this is my urls.py:

```
path("process_order/",views.processOrder,name="process_order"),

    path("handlerequest/",views.handlerequest,name="handlerequest"),
```

This code is not working . After clicking the payment button I am getting this error:
`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`
This error is referring to the submitformdata() in my javascript code.

I want to workout a way so that once a person clicks on the payment button and his transaction is completed then his data is submitted to the database otherwise not for which I have written the code in handlerequest.
Please help me out.

Comment: Have you found the answer for it. I am following the same blog but for django rest framework can you give some suggestions on how to do it in drf.

Comment: Yes I have solved it and I have faced it multiple times and I was able to get through it.If you are using Paytm then you can ask a seperate question and I will try to help

Comment: I can't ask questions can you provide source code for it please